# Is the complete English translation of the Padma Purana available online?

Tags: puranas, translation-request, padma-purana

The [Padma Purana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padma_Purana) is one of the eighteen Mahapuranas, and it includes many important things, including a retelling of the Ramayana, a religious dialogue between Shiva and Parvati known the Shiva Gita, and several Sahasranamams (lists of 1000 names of a god), including a Vishnu Sahasranam (different from [the more famous one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_sahasranama) that Bhishma told in the Mahabharata), a Rama Sahasranamam, and a Venkatesha Sahasranam (in praise of [Venkateshwara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara)).

As far as I know, the only unabridged English translation of the Padma Purana is [this 10-volume translation](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/padma-purana-ten-volumes-IDF395/) by N.A. Deshpande from the 1950's, published by Motilal Banarsidass.  My question is, is the whole translation available for free on the internet?  I've found most of the volumes of it online, as I discuss in my answer, but the whole thing still eludes me.

Naturally, since this is a reputable site, I only want legal sources, nothing that involves any copyright-infringement.

Comment: "a religious dialogue between Shiva and Parvati known the Shiva Gita.".... Shiva Gita is not dialogue between Shiva and Parvati... It is dialogue between Lord Rama and Lord Shiva... but there are various places in Padma Purana which contains dialogue of Shiva and Parvati...

Comment: All 10 volumes here.https://archive.org/details/PadmaPuranaVol05BhumiAndPatalaKhandaPages15651937ENGMotilalBanarsidass1990_201901/Padma-Purana%20Vol-01%20-%20Srshti-Khanda%20-%20pages%201-423%20ENG%20Motilal%20Banarsidass%201988/page/n113/mode/2up

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've so far found two legal sources that have certain volumes of the Motilal-Banarsidass translation of the Padma Purana:

1. [DSpace](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/), the digital repository of the West Bengal Public Library Network, which has books in PDF format, but breaks each book into 80-page chunks.
2. The [Digital Library of India](http://www.dli.ernet.in/) (DLI), which currently has lots of books only in TIFF format but is in the process of converting them all to PDF.  I converted them to PDF using [DLI Downloader](https://github.com/cancerian0684/dli-downloader/releases).  (I used version 5.4, available [here](http://code.google.com/p/dli-downloader/), which is the latest version compatible with Windows XP).

So here are the volumes I've found so far using these two sources (remember there are 10 volumes total):

[Volume 3](http://gdurl.com/wLOT/download) (from DLI)

[Volume 4](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12948) (from DSpace)

[Volume 5](http://gdurl.com/Tcco/download) (from DLI)

[Volume 6](http://gdurl.com/ZtXX/download) (from DLI)

[Volume 7](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12949) (from DSpace)

[Volume 8](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12952) (from DSpace)

[Volume 9](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12954) (from Dspace)

[Volume 10](http://gdurl.com/CsMd/download) (from DLI)

Note that the index of the Padma Purana is at the end of volume 10.

I also found links to Volume 1 and Volume 2, but I haven't confirmed that the links are legal, so I'm refraining from posting them in case they infringes on copyright.  Does anyone know whether this book is in the public domain, or whether it's still under copyright? (I asked this question in [Meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332/what-is-the-copyright-status-of-indian-books) as well.)

Comment: Can you share me the links for vol. 1? You can add me in a chat-room and share me the link there.

Answer (score 1):

Padma Purana Vol 2 is available [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=FF76E5FB53795C42&id=FF76E5FB53795C42%21109). I ask  if anyone has found Vol 1, please kindly post the link.

Comment: My profile has my mail id. I can provide you complete version of Padma Purana (15 MB) which is text searchable. (Thanks to Tezz as he provided me this great unabridged version of Padma Purana).

Comment: @TheDestroyer Could you please share the PDF with me? I've been looking for Vol 1 for a while and wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @Arya I'm not sure if i can share it here. You can send me a mail and i will send you. My mail id is in my profile description.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thank you. :) I'll mail you now.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the whole Padma Purana in English [here](http://download1591.mediafire.com/e57jb5qsa3tg/a173i1g42f5f15t/Purana+-+Padma+Purana+-+Eng.pdf).

Comment: We refrained to post that link here as we don't know exact copyright status of the book.