# Is there any description available of Kalpavriksh?

Tags: samudra-manthan

It is said that during Samudra Manthan, appeared the wish fulfilling tree called Kalpavriksha. It was later taken by Devas. But, is there any more description of this tree, how it looked like, was it different from other trees, were there any fruits on it. Also, does it existed prior to Samudra Manthan as well, how it fulfilled wishes. Also, do we have any stories where anyone used this tree to get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per what i know, i only remember of Lord Shiv and Goddess Parvati getting their daughter Ashok sundari from kalpavriksha. I am not sure but i think this is given under Padma Purana. But i donot know which verse, etc says about this incident.

Comment: See my answer here for a link to the potion of the Padma Purana discussing Ashokasundari: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2029/36