# Who is the eldest son of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, puranas, ganesha, kartikeya

In South India, people worship Lord Ganesh and consider him to be Lord Shiva's first son and elder to Lord Kartikeya.

In the North and remaining parts of India however, people have a faith that Lord Kartikeya is Shiva's eldest son.

So, who is the eldest son of Lord Shiva?

Also, who is Lord Ayyappan? Does he belong to Lord Shiva's family? Does Lord Shiva also have a daughter?

Comment: There's no consensus on who is elder and younger. "When Agni stole seed of Lord Shiva, Parvati Devi felt sad and **immediately** made a boy out of mud. After Rudra decapitated this boy. Simultaneously, seed of Rudra was transformed to Kartikeya". So, there's no consensus.

Comment: Parvati Devi made a boy for preserving her privacy and that is Ganesh.He interfere in the way of Lord Shiva and for that his head was removed by Lord Shiva. As per the request of devas, Lord Shiva created Kartikeya from his third eye's spark for killing Suran.

Comment: Are you sure that Lord Ganesha is worshiped first because he is elder OR because it is customary to worship him at the beginning of any ritual?

Comment: @PonmariSubramanian Yeah but she immediately made a body after stealing of Shiva's seed.

Comment: The question is not that Rickross.. Who is the elder one?

Comment: @AnilKumar The thing to be clear is that which incident happened first. If we found that we can unloose the answer for this question

Comment: You won't get an answer because all Tamil texts and saints say that Ganesha is elder (and unmarried) and all Sanskrit texts say that Muruga was elder and unmarried. @Anil your consensus is the most sensible thing about their birth that I have read.

Comment: @Surya I read this in Shiva Purana from [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3825/3500). Author says Parvati made a boy immediately from mud.

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23714/which-scriptures-mention-kartikeya-as-the-elder-brother-of-ganesha

Comment: Tarakasura's reign was later than Ganesa's birth. Skanda took birth to kill Tarakasura. So Ganesa is elder

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the famous names of Sri Ganapaty is **"Skandapurvaja"** which literally means "the elder brother of Skanda or Lord Karthikeya". So, Ganapaty is the eldest son.

Skandapurvaja -- One who is born (ja) before (purva) Karthikeya (Skanda).

[108 names of Ganapaty,with 82nd in the list being "Skandapurvaja"](http://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/108-names-of-ganesha-in-sanskrit_26.html5)

There is a Ganesha Asta Namavali Stotram found in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana.It was narrated by Lord Vishnu to Godess Parvati.That stotram has the name **Guhaagrajam** which has the same meaning as Skandapurvaja.

> Vande Guhaagrajam Devam Sarvadevaagra pujitam/
>  Yetanmaashtakam
> Durgey Namaabhih samyuktam param,
>  Putrasya pasya Vedey cha tadaa
> kopam thathaa kuru/
>  Yetanmaashtakam Stotram naanaartha samyutam
> shubham,
>  Trisandhyam yah pathennithyam sa sukhee sarvato
> jayee/
>  Tato Vighnaam palaayantey vaina teyaad yathoragah,
> Ganeswaraprasaadena mahajnaani bhaved dhruvam/
>  Putraarthi labhatey
> putram Bhaaryaarthi vipulam striam,
>  Maha jadam Kaveendrascha
> vidyaa vaancham bhaved dhruvam/
>
> (Mother Parvati! your son has eight names viz. Ganesha, Ekadanta,
> Heramba, Vighnanayaka, Lambodara, Shurpakarna, Gajavaktra, and
> Guhaagraja. Please listen to the meanings of these names; this Great
> Stotra is the essence of several Stotras and is the demolisher of all
> kinds of obstacles

[image]

[image]

Also, the Shiva Purana mentiones birth of Ganesha during Svetakalpa and implies that Ganesha is younger son of Lord Shiva (at Shveta Kalpa).

Sri Ayyappa was created from an union of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu (in the Mohini form), but he is not usually considered a member of Lord Shiva's family, however, in a Puja we do see his Pushpa Arcahna (worship by flowers)  by the following Mantras which uses 8 names of Lord Shiva. :

> Om Bhavasya Devasya Sutaya Namaha, Om Sarvasya Devasya Sutaya Namaha,
> ..... Om Mahato Devasya Sutaya Namaha.

[image]

So,he is considered as Lord Shiva's son.

Now coming to the question-Does Lord Shiva have a daughter?

According to the Padma Purana the answer is yes and her name is **AshokaSundari**

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashokasundari):

> Ashokasundari (Sanskrit: अशोकसुंदरी, Aśokasundarī), also spelt as
> Ashoka sundari is a character in the Padma Purana who is described as
> the daughter of the deities Shiva and Parvati.
>
> Ashokasundari was created from the wish-fulfilling tree Kalpavriksha
> when Parvati wished for reducing her loneliness. The words in her name
> are derived from her creation. "Ashok" refers to the easing of
> Parvati's "shok," which means sorrow, while "sundari" means "beautiful
> girl".

UPDATE:

In [Ganesha Pancharatnam](http://greenmesg.org/stotras/ganesha/ganesha_pancharatnam.php), Adi Shankara also mentions Lord Ganesha as **Puraripurvanandanam** or the earlier (purva) son (nandana) of Purari i.e the enemy (ari) of the three cities (tripura) i.e of Lord Shiva.

> अकिंचनार्तिमार्जनं चिरन्तनोक्तिभाजनं
> **पुरारिपूर्वनन्दनं** सुरारिगर्वचर्वणम् ।
>  प्रपञ्चनाशभीषणं धनंजयादिभूषणम्
>  कपोलदानवारणं भजे पुराणवारणम् ॥४॥

Comment: Does Skanda Purana say Ganesha is elder than Kartikeya other than by name "Skandapurvaja"? Which Purana has Ganesha 108 names?

Comment: @AnilKumar Lord Vishnu narrates one Ganesha stuti called Ganesha Asta Namavali stotram to Devi Parvati in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana.It has the name Guhaagraja .I have added couple of screenshots in my answer.

Comment: What's the literal translation of 'Guhaagrajam'? I know 'agraja' [means](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=agraja&direction=SE&link=yes&choice=yes) firstborn. EDIT: Ok, Guhan or Guruguha ("cave-dweller").

Comment: @sv Guha or Guhan is another name of Skanda(karthikeya)

Comment: @Rickross Yes, I was looking for the meaning behind that name. So in this case 'Guhaagrajam' means 'elder to cave-dweller (Karthikeya)'.

Comment: Who's the spouse of `Ashokasundari`?

Comment: @venkat It's Nahusha; see my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2029/36

Comment: You should consider https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23714/which-scriptures-mention-kartikeya-as-the-elder-brother-of-ganesha as well...

Comment: That does not prove anything for me to be frank.. unanimously Lord Ganesha is considered as the elder one.. if someone can find names of Lord Karthikeya like " Ganapatypurvaja" etc, then there will appear some contradiction..but nothing of that sort for the time being..@YDS