# Which scriptures mention Kartikeya as the elder brother of Ganesha?

Tags: ganesha, kartikeya

[This Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10867/12304) mention Ganesha as the elder brother of Kartikeya. But most of the North Indians believe that Kartikeya is elder. So, is there any scripture which mention Kartikeya as the elder brother of Ganesha?

Comment: I don't think Ganesha was elder because Tadkasura got boon that he can only be killed by son of Shiva. And he got kill by Kartikay, not by Ganesha. If Ganesha is elder then he would have kill Tadkasura to make heaven free from him. Why his death need to wait till birth of second son of Shiva? It's senseless.

Comment: Many puranas mention Ganesha as elder son of Shiva.

Comment: @thedestroyer In those puranas, who killed Tadkasura?

Comment: @Rishabh Skanda Purana says Ganesha too participated in Tarakasura and Kartikeya war.

Comment: @thedestroyer Seriously, now I am started to get doubt on Puranas itself. Your given info raised too many questions in my mind. But not gonna ask them else this comment section will get full of series of conversation. I will pretend like I didn't read anything in this post coz not gonna stress myself by reading different things in different puranas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This excerpt](https://ia801302.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/20/items/SivaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart2/Siva%20Purana%20-%20J.L.Shastri%20-%20Part%202_jp2.zip&file=Siva%20Purana%20-%20J.L.Shastri%20-%20Part%202_jp2/Siva%20Purana%20-%20J.L.Shastri%20-%20Part%202_0308.jp2&scale=1.263157894736842&rotate=0) from the Kumara Khanda of the Shiva Purana describes Kartikeya participating in the battle between Shiva and Ganesha that happened right after Ganesha was born:

> [Shiva] issued directives to Indra and other gods, to the Ganas led by **the six-faced Kumara** and to goblins, ghosts and spirits. At the bidding of Shiva they all desired to kill Ganesha. Lifting their weapons in a suitable manner hey came there from all directions.

So in this account, Kartikeya is older than Ganesha.