# Did Lord Vishnu build Sri Jagannath Temple situated at Puri?

Tags: vishnu, temple

Is there any story, that tells about who had built the [Sri Jagannath temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagannath_Temple,_Puri) at Puri?

Are these following facts true?

1. Lord Vishnu himself came to Puri to build the Jagannath temple.
2. After 10,000 years, Lord Brahma himself came there as a priest to inaugurate the Jagannath temple?

Comment: Welcome back! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which scripture mentions Vishwakarma made the idols at Jagannatha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29132/which-scripture-mentions-vishwakarma-made-the-idols-at-jagannatha)

Comment: One clarification...are u asking about temple or idols?... temple was built by King Indrdyuman... Idols by Lord Vishnu (as per few Puranas) or Vishwakarma (as per few other Puranas) as mentioned in the linked Q..

Comment: Thanks..., My question is about the temple. not idols. @YDS