# Who are the daughters of Lord Shiva? What are their stories?

Tags: shiva, goddess

We all know that Shiva has two sons, Kartikeya and Ganesha. But I heard that he has three daughters too. I also heard that these daughters are worshipped in some parts of India.

Is this true? If yes, who are the daughters of Lord Shiva? What are their stories?

Comment: The question sounds about discussion rather than question, for instance "Surprising but true! Shiva’s three daughters" in the body of question and also according to the nature of Q/A, it looks about advertising/discussing blog and hence doesn't qualify as real question. (As Hinduism.SE is Q/A site, this type of discussion would be off-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are trying to advertise your blog. This is not encouraged in this site. Make edits to your question and answer to fit the rules in [hep centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @Pandya made edits to look like a question

Comment: @SreeCharan See above comment and the modified question. OP is not advertising in the question but only his answer, so I don't think we should block the question. You could vote on the answer if you don't like it.

Comment: Related [Why is Lord Shiva's daughter Ashokasundari not worshipped?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2023/3500)