# What scriptures describe the story of Rama visiting Vishnu in Vaikuntha?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, puranas, padma-purana

Most people only know of occasions in which two different incarnations of Vishnu met, for instance the encounter between Rama and Parashurama in the Ramayana.  What is not as well known, however, is that Vishnu's incarnation Krishna (along with Arjuna) once met Vishnu himself, as I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6672/36).  But apparently this isn't the only such incident.  [This excerpt](http://gdurl.com/US4e) from a journal paper published by Asiatic Researches in 1810 recounts a story it says is in the Patala Kanda of Padma Purana, about an occasion when Rama, accompanied by Shiva, goes to Vaikuntha, the abode of Vishnu.

> In the Padma Purana, section of Patala, or the infernal regions, Suta is introduced relating the most wonderful exploits, and mighty deeds of Ramachandra, who came originally from the White Island, as we have seen before[.]...  Ramachandra, having the advantage of a self-moving car, performed in a few days, in company with Mahadeva....  He then advanced towards the Lokaloka mountains, and Shambu or Shiva ... ascended his vimana, or vehicle, and with wonderful speed, soon overtook Rama.  They then descried the Lokaloka mountain, on the summit of which are the paths of the planets.... Thus assisted with the refulgence of Shambhu, they arrived into the land of darkness, where there are no living creatures.  There, one hundred millions of Yojanas from the limits of light, in that land of darkness, is Maharajatabhumi[.]. In the middle of it is Narayanapura, resplendent like one hundred millions of suns.  Rama was astonished at this wonderful sight, in the land of the blessed, and the paradise of Vishnu....
>
> Rama ... immediately made puja to Achyuta, or the incorruptible god.... Vishnu and Lakshmi, with myriads of yogis, came out to meet their guests, no having worshipped them, carried them to Narayanapura.  Vishnu asked, "How have you come to this place inaccessible to mortals?" ... Shambhu answered "He is a portion of your essence: we saw a path, and we followed it, and he wishes very much to see your consort."

Rama is eager to see Lakshmi, as Sita has apparently died already, but he leaves quickly because he has taken an Ekapatni Vrata.

But my question is not about the story itself, but rather about where it's from.  The journal paper claims it's from the Patala Kanda of the Padma Purana.  You can read the Padma Purana using the links in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/792/36); I can't seem to find the story at first glance.

So does anyone know what chapter it's in, or whether it's found in other scriptures?

Comment: BTW Apart from Rama and ParashuRama meeting during Ramayana, I think Krishna and ParashuRama also met. During which the the later gave Sudarshana Chakra to Krishna.

Comment: @iammilind As far as I know, Parashurama giving Krishna the Sudarshana Chakra has no basis in Hindu scripture, despite it being shown in the Mahabharat TV serial.  What does have a scriptural basis is the story given in my answer here, about Krishna obtaining it from Varuna the ocean god: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1991/36  In any case, there is one occasion when Krishna and Parashurama met in Duryodhana's court, as I discuss in this answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2395/36 Parashurama tries warning Duryodhana about how powerful Krishna is, but Duryodhana doesn't listen.

Comment: You might be right  bout the myth regarding ParashuRama giving to Krishna. There is another version of [Sudarshan chakra procurement](http://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/how-did-lord-krushna-acquire-sudarshan-chakra.html#2)

Comment: @iammilind I don't think stories A, B, and C in section 2 have a basis in Hindu scripture either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This story is mentioned in [Padma Purana Patala Khanda Chapter 105](http://gdurl.com/Cj54):

> 10-14a. Having heard these words spoken, the sages got angry and said: "Why have you told us these very auspicious words now? Due to your attachment to your beloved you made an unmeaning talk. You did not do our words (i.e. what we had 
>   asked you)." Then from the face of  Sambhu who was full of anger, a very wonderful flame went out; and she too had a > terrible face. She seized the wife of a certain sage and was intent upon fleeing quickly, but was frightened on seeing Rama. Rama too said, "I shall free the brahmana-woman." Again and again talking of liberating (the brahmana-woman), he went by Puspaka only.
>
> 14b-17a. Rama did not remember (i.e. he forgot) to fix the arrow onto the bow. Sambhu also, seeing very auspicious forests and abodes, and strange cities, did not remember Rama. Then in a moment Rama reached the great mountain Lokaloka. Then Rama, seeing the mountain full of houses and paths (said to the brahmanas): "O illustrious brahmanas, tell me which way the brahmana-woman has gone."
>
> 17b-20a. They said: "This way she has gone to the dark side of the mountain." Rama with a pale face thought: 'Oh, it is bad'. Then Sambhu, of great lustre, gave matchless light. Due to the prowess of that light, Rama went after that female deity to whom sacrifices are offered for destructive and magical purposes. The great region was full of darkness and without beings. From the primordial egg to the fragment of a broken jar, it spread over a hundred crores of yojanas.
>
> 20b-23a. **In the darkness was settled a great silver (piece of) land. There was the city of Narayana (i.e. Visnu), having lustre 
>   like that of a crore of suns. Seeing it, the best sages along with Rama, were amazed. Thinking (i.e. they thought): -What is
>   this? How can we enter it? Could it be the fire at the time of the end of the world due to the magic power of the highest
>   lord? Shall we die today or shall we have bliss?**'
>
> 23b-30. When the sages, along with Rama, were thus full of anxiety, Sambhu said: "ORama,listen to what I tell you today.
>   For you I have brought about this illusion. This is no wonder. **This is the great city of Narayana (i.e. Visnu). It is bright with lustre. It cannot be destroyed by heat or cold. It is accessible through knowledge (only). It is not visible to the (physical) eyes. Look above at Brahma and others who are worshipping it. Look in all directions at the pure sages who are worshipping it. Look at the four Vedas, praising the Highest Position (i.e. the highest god). O Raghava, see this Highest Lustre which the meditating sages like Sanaka, resorting to abstract meditation, are meditating upon. See also this Romasa going round and saluting. Look at these crores and crores of best sages like Valakhilya. Look at the Highest Position (i.e. the highest god) being worshipped by all women like Laksmi. It is described as the Brahman having a form and without a form. The ignorant do not (i.e. cannot) see it. (Only) those having the eyes of know- ledge (can) see it.**"
>
> 31-34. On (hearing) the words of Sambhu all worshipped Acyuta, so also GirikarnI, Tulasi, Mallika and Maruta. (They saw) the high-souled ones worshipping the illustrious Janardana. They saw Narada having matted hair and a lute, uttering loudly the word (i.e. name) Narayana, having a large beard and 
>   a sacred thread. He too thought to his mind: 'Who is this?'He (i.e. Narada), full of joy, fell at the feet of Sambhu.
>
> 35-36a. The sage mentally muttered the five-lettered incantation dedicated to Siva. "lam blessed; I am favoured; today
>   my life is fruitful, (since) I have known your place which is saluted by Brahma and others, which is inaccessible".
>
> 36b-42. Then Sambhu said to Narada: "Do not say so. Behave with me in such a way that they do not recognise me. Go quickly and tell Visnu about my arrival in a short time." Then, he hurriedly went and informed Visnu of everything. Then he, the yogin, taking the auspicious water with materials for worship, along with Laksmi, and surrounded by crores and crores (of followers), seizing Narada with his hand went (forth to greet him). The word Visnu does not fit in the verse! He, having Garuda as his banner said: "Salutation, salutation to Sankara." Visnu honoured all with materials of worship and water for washing the feet. He, of an immeasurable intellect, made them enter (i.e. took them into) the auspicious Narayana pura (i.e. city of Visnu). Then remaining in the best house, **Narayana said: "How have these come (here)? Who is this king ?of great glory? Human beings cannot enter this (place). This is inaccessible even to Brahma and others."**
>
> **Sambhu said:** 
>   43-46a. We, dressed as sages, have come (here); and this valourous king is Ramacandra who is a portion of you. O 
>   Kesava, he desires to see your wife.
>   Narayana (i.e. Visnu) saying, "All right", said to Rama "Enter (here)". Then having entered the residence, having seen Laksmi, and bowing through modesty he saluted her, and said (these) meritorious words (to her): "I am blessed; there is no doubt about it. Tell me what you feel."
>
> **Sri Devi said:** 
>   46b-48. O Raghava, you are young; you are attracted by love for sensual enjoyments; you are handsome. That Sita, beautiful in all limbs, is your wife. Formerly you were separated from her, and being afflicted due to separation from her were, as it were, sinking. Tell me all that or you will not speak. Words accompanied by smile attract the hearts of young persons.
>
> 49-53. Having heard all those words, Ramabhadra who was restrained and composed, having bowed down his lotus-
>   like face, desired to go out from there. Having tormented the best among the Raghus, with a lotus—an arrow of Cupid-
>   goddess Padma, to whom Padmavana was dear, went out after him. Knowing Rama to be one devoted to his only wife, they 
>   came to the king (i.e. Rama) whose entire body was trembling and whose steps were faltering. **Seeing that Siva and Visnu were 
>   very much amazed. "Oh, the firmness of his mind! His heart is not subjugated by Cupid. See his controlled steadiness. Rama 
>   is well-known due to that. In every respect he has auspiciousness. Nothing inauspicious is (to be found) anywhere (about him)." Then Rama said (these) words: "O lord, I would go."**

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  You should add a link to the Padma Purana chapter: http://gdurl.com/Cj54

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan I tried to add that link.. but It didn't displayed as link.. I think I donot know properly to add links...

Comment: OK, I added it for you.  For future reference, here's the format you should follow: [text](URL). And when writing the URL, make sure to include the http://.

Comment: @Tezz Are Puranas you have text searchable ?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Narayana knew about Rama. Then why did He ask Shiva who Rama was?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah, he knew who his own incarnation was, he was just saying that as part of his Lila.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Thanks for your reference..

Comment: @The Destroyer some Purans are searchable and some are not...

Comment: Can you explain the story as the Padma Purana does not say it clearly. Why does Shiva take Rama to Vaikuntha and what happens to the Brahmana lady

Comment: What a fantastic story! Never knew Rama also met lord Vishnu!