# Are there instances wherein a God/Goddess met his/her incarnation?

Tags: gods, avatars, goddess

Are there instances from the Hindu mythology wherein Gods have met their incarnations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the eighty-ninth chapter of the tenth canto of the Srimad Bhagavatam mentions a story where Shree Krishna meets Sriman Narayana, along with Arjuna:

> **Lord Kṛṣṇa offered homage to Himself in this boundless form, and Arjuna, astonished at the sight of Lord Mahā-Viṣṇu, bowed down as well.** Then, as the two of them stood before Him with joined palms, the almighty Mahā-Viṣṇu, supreme master of all rulers of the universe, smiled and spoke to them in a voice full of solemn authority. (Srimad Bhagavatam 10.89.57)

You can read the complete story [here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/89/chapter-view).

Comment: Rama also met Vishnu. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11410/3500