# How do gods decide when to incarnate and when to assume a human form bypassing the birthing process?

Tags: ramayana, gods, avatars, indra

In both Rāmāyaṇa and Mahābhārata, we see Indra taking a human form during what appears to be *emergency* situations.

When Indra wants to rob Gautama off of his ascetic power he suddenly decides to take a human form which is an exact replica of Gautama.

Similarly, to try and disrupt Viśvāmitra's penance to become a brahmarṣi, Indra suddenly appears before him as a brāhmaṇa and begs/steals his only meal in a long time.

In Mahābhārata, Indra again presents himself as a brāhmaṇa (out of thin air) to steal Karṇa's armour.

1. First off, are these *on-demand* assumptions of human form considered incarnations/avatars?
2. Secondly, how do gods decide when to follow the due process i.e., enter a mother's womb and take birth in a certain family. And just drive the events that just lead up to the actual purpose of their incarnation – versus – just taking the right human form at the right moment?

   For example, in Gautama's case, why didn't Indra just take birth as Gautama's twin brother?

Comment: why would you think that 'assuming' a human form is the same as incarnating??

Comment: I think gods have the power to take any forms whenever they wish.. but incarnating is different from that

Comment: I think Avtar/incarnation is not used for simply changing appearance to do something. Avtar has a greater purpose and has a longer life. Moreover if you ask me then I would say that Avtaar can also be the ones in whom, the other people see the qualities of some God, and start calling them as an avtar of that God.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? If you're a god, 'assuming' a human form has a purpose. Isn't that an avatar is all about @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: It's like asking on what basis parents decide when to patiently teach their child not to touch fire, and when they suddenly snatch a kid about to touch fire. Also, an action that serves multiple purposes is the hallmark of advanced soul - '2 mangoes with 1 stone'. when they decide to take birth, they also fulfill boons of the parents, while also satisfying various other rules and conditions like urgency and time. when Krishna was born, Vasudeva & Devaki had a boon remaining from previous birth etc. And other times, when matters are more urgent, they suddenly appear/disappear.

Comment: @sv. in an incarnation the god (deva/devi) is still present but sends a small part of himself to earth. In this case it is Indra himself disguising himself. So no an incarnation is different than a god disguising himself. The proof of this is e.g. Rama meeting Vishnu while Rama is an avatara. So the anwer of question 1: no. As for your second question. It is just a matter of practicality: Rama and Krishna had to stay for a long time on earth so there is no time for Vishnu to do that so he sends multiple incarnations (even more than 1 at the same time if needed).

Comment: @Wikash Where did you hear this: "Rama meeting Vishnu while Rama is an avatar" - this must be an interpolation. 'In this case it is Indra himself disguising' - I'm asking how do they decide when to appear as themselves & when to incarnate?

Comment: @sv. See here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/what-scriptures-describe-the-story-of-rama-visiting-vishnu-in-vaikuntha?r=SearchResults your question is repeated. It's just determined based on practicality devas/devis have stuff to do.