# What are various subsects of Shankara Advaita school?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, sects

What are different sub sects of AdiShankaracharya's Advaita school?

Comment: Related: [What are the philosophical differences between the Vivarana and Bhamati schools of Advaita Vedanta?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31692/277)