# Was Shatrughna an avatar of Vishnu's Sudarshan Chakra?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama

My friend told me that Lord Rama's brother Shatrughna was an avatar of Lord Vishnu's Sudarshan Chakra. Is this real?

Comment: I think Bharata is an incarnation of the Sudarshana Chakra and Shatrughna is an incarnation of the Panchajanya Shankha.

Comment: According to [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatrughna), Shatrughna is supposed to be the reincarnation of Vishnu's sacred conch.

Comment: bharathan is incarnation of sudharsana chakra
lakshmanan is incarnation of adhiseshan (5 headed snake)
chathrugnan is incarnation of panchajanya sangu

Comment: Shatrugan was the chakra and Barath was the sanku

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from [this](http://www.astrojyoti.com/padmapurana-10.htm) chapter of the Padma Purana where Lord Shiva is describing about the various avataras of Lord Vishnu to Goddess Parvati:

> Describing about Sri Ram’s incarnation Lord Mahadeva told
>   Parvati–‘Once, Swayambhuva Manu had expressed his desire of having
>   Lord Vishnu as his son to which Lord Vishnu had agreed....
>
> Continuing with the tale of Sri Ram, Lord Mahadeva told
>   Parvati–Dasharath requested Vashishth to perform the Jaatkarm Sanskar
>   of Sri Ram. In course of time Kaikeyi gave birth to **Bharat–an
>   incarnation of Panchajanya conch**. Similarly, Sumitra gave birth to
>   two sons–Laxman and Shatrughan. **Laxman was the incarnation of
>   Sheshnag while Shatrughan was the incarnation of Sudarshan Chakra.**

Comment: That link is to an abridged summary of the Padma Purana.  You should instead cite the unabridged translation of the Padma Purana given in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/792/36

Comment: Why? what's wrong with this source?It gives the answer correctly and its a reliable source as well, anyways finding the exact page from your given link might take a lot of time.

Comment: Yeah, your link is certainly a reliable enough source for the standards of this site.  I'm just saying it would be better if you gave an actual citation to the Padma Purana.