# How concept of sisters of Sita: Urmila, Shrutakeerti and Mandavi can be reconciled with concept of Mahalakshmi?

Tags: avatars, lakshmi, sita

We know, Sri Rama was [Avatar of Lord Vishnu](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga18/bala_18_frame.htm), Lakshama was [one quarter portion of Vishnu](http://ramayana.tigercoder.com/template.php?c=07uttara) <sup>[a]</sup> or avatar of Adisesha. Shatrugna and Bharatha were incarnations of [Sudarshana Chakra and Panchajanya Shankha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11311/3500) respectively.

These three brothers, Lakshamana, Shatrugna and Bharatha married Urmila, Shrutakeerti and Mandavi respectively. Rama married Sita who was incarnation of Goddess lakshmi. As portions of Vishnu were present in His brothers, portions of Goddess Lakshmi must be present in Sita's sisters.

So, how can be three sisters of Sita reconciled with concept of Goddess Lakshmi?

---

<sub>[a] Chapter 106 of Uttarakanda</sub>

Comment: I assume that Urmila, Mandavi, and Shrutakirti were incarnations of the wives of Adiseshan, Sudarshana, and Panchajanya, although of course those goddesses might in turn be incarnations of Lakshmi.  Now I think in some Purana the wife of Vishnu's Vyuha form Sankarshana is mentioned, so that's who Urmila would be an incarnation of.  But I don't know anything about the wives of Sudarshana and Panchajanya, if they're even married.

Comment: I don't think weapons have wives. BTW, who is wife of Adisesha?

Comment: @Keshav The wife of Sudarshana is called Kirti (fame) as told by Dushyant Sridhar in his discourse on Sudarshana Vaibhavam. So similarly Shankha will have a Shakti and these Devis would have incarnated as the daughters of Janaka and Kusadhvaja.

Comment: Those 3 sisters of Sita r said to be incarnation of 3 lotuses in hand of ma lakshmi.