# Why did Lord Rama need Lakshmana around all the time?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama, lakshmana

If Rama was an avatar of Lord Vishnu, why did he need Lakshmana around him all the time?

Comment: Lakshmana was avatar of Adi Shesha. Vishnu and Adi Shesha are always together. Ram Lakshmana, Krishna Balram etc..

Comment: Yes Chinmay is right.You can refer to the answer here:http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/was-shatrughna-an-avatar-of-vishnus-sudarshan-chakra/11311#11311

Answer (score 1):

Vishnu is often depicted as resting on Shesha. Shesha is also considered a servant as well as a manifestation of Vishnu. He is said to have descended to Earth in two human forms or avatars:

[image]

Lakshmana, brother of Rama;

Balarama, brother of Krishna.

Sesha is always with Lord Vishnu so When Vishnu took avtar in the form of Lord Rama Sesha took avtar in the form of Lakshman to protect and serve Lord Rama.

Reference Link https://www.templepurohit.com/lakshman-balrama-avatars-of-sheshnag/

Comment: I think Sesha and other Devas helped Lord Vishnu during only certain Avatars. But during Varaha, Matsya Sesha didn't incarnate.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/597/3500) to know what sources are best.

Comment: @rsp: All content is taken from [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-lord-Rama-needed-lakshmana-all-the-time/answer/Kakashi-Malav-Gupta) & Quora is not authentic source to cite. See [references on meta](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/597/3500).

Comment: @Trichakra Some of your answers also cite quora.com and others lack references completely, I suggest you too fix some of your answers. Citing directly from scriptures would help. Thanks.