# How could Bharata and Shatrughna be incarnations of inanimate objects?

Tags: vishnu, philosophy, avatars, atma

From [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11311/8696) answer, we find

> Continuing with the tale of Sri Ram, Lord Mahadeva told Parvati–Dasharath requested Vashishth to perform the Jaatkarm Sanskar of Sri Ram. In course of time Kaikeyi gave birth to **Bharat–an incarnation of Panchajanya conch**. Similarly, Sumitra gave birth to two sons–Laxman and Shatrughan. Laxman was the incarnation of Sheshnag while **Shatrughan was the incarnation of Sudarshan Chakra**.

How non living things (insentient beings) like **Sudarshan chakra** & **conch** could take avatar?

Comment: I think Shanka and Chakra are different. They are divine weapons.

Comment: Bharata was an incarnation of the god of the Sudarshana Chakra and Shatrughna was an incarnation of the god of the Panchajanya Shankha.  Both of those gods are Nitya Suris or eternal associates of Vishnu.  Bharata and Shatrughna were not incarnations of inanimate objects.

Comment: Sankha and Chakra have chaitanya. They are not inanimate or jaDa.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Chonch and Chakra have chaitanya- give Scriptural references

Comment: From my understanding, every thing we see there is Karya and Karan. There is Fire and there is fire lord AgniDev. Surya is the Karya but SuryaDev is Karan. the same way from what we see sudarshan chakra is weapon, but There may be a divine form of Sudarshan and Panchajanya.