# Who is Vijayavalli, wife of the Sudarshana Chakra?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, weapon, sudarshana-chakra

I just performed a Griha Pravesam, the Hindu house warming ceremony, and I noticed an interesting Mantra that the priest chanted.  The Mantra, which I assume was from the Pancharatra Agamas, was addressed to Sudarshana, referred to as Chakrathalwar by Sri Vaishnavas, the god of Vishnu's Sudarshana Chakra. What I found interesting is that the Mantra addressed him as "Vijayavalli Sametha Sudarshana", meaning "Sudarshana accompanied by Vijayavalli".

This construction is usually used in the context of husband and wife.  And indeed Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijayavalli) that Vijayavalli is Sudarshana's wife.  So my question is, who is Vijayavalli? Whose daughter is she, and how did Sudarshana marry her? And given that Rama's brother Bharata and Parashurama's enemy Kartavirya Arjuna were incarnations of Sudarshana, were their wives incarnations of Vijayavalli?

Do any Pancharatra Agamas or Puranas shed light on this?

Comment: One clarification here, Sudarshana's incarnation was Shatrughana or Bharata?

Comment: @YDS Shatrugna.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, I also heard the same but Keshav Srinivasan denied this on https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/was-shatrughna-an-avatar-of-vishnus-sudarshan-chakra and here also he mentioned Bharata so may be there is some other scripture which say Bharata was incarnation of Sudarshana chakra...

Comment: a weapon has a wife??????????????????????????

Comment: The god of a weapon has a wife.  And for the record, my parents are the homeowners, not me.

Comment: What a typical Iyengar name for the wife of a god!

Comment: "VIjayavalli" as a girl's name would be close to non-existent in North India.  Practically certain its a late Southern Vaishnavite concoction.  Worshiping Vishnu's weapon is also I think unknown in North India, where it is simply an appendage of Vishnu.

Comment: Last I checked there is no Hindu Pope in North India

Comment: @SK The worship of Sudarsana is discussed in great detail in Pancharatra Agamas.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan - that may be so - only shows how late these agamas are and that they are more or less of Southern origin.  Southerners and perhaps Bengalis turned the simple Vedic religion into something so elaborate and fantastic.

Comment: @SK Alternatively, it might show that the Pancharatra Agamas are ancient and that the methodology by which one evaluates the antiquity of a text needs to be reevaluated.

Comment: @keshav srinivasan - you should read people like Srikant Talageri.  The way people are named has a chronology - he gives a name "panduranga" which is late, never occurring in the Vedas.  "VIjayavalli" overwhelmingly proves it is late and Southern.  I doubt that Iyengar girls from educated urban families  will be named "nappinnai", "amirtavalli", "ranganayaki" et al. in the future.

Comment: @keshav srinivasan https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emToNbjqVnA  Could not see a relation between Swamivari purifying snaan and the Chakra.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan - YOUR first name shows that names have a chronology.  Your name is in Hindi not Sanskrit or Tamil.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Vijayavalli has another name "Vijayasri", according to [this chapter](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.21516/page/n186/mode/1up) from Narada Purana:-

> May the deity accompanied by **Vijayasri (glory of conquest)** protect my upper direction. He is the lord himself holding the thousand-spoked (discus). He is the person striking terror into all wicked ones.

It is not directly mentiones her, but it is implies that she was his shakti.

The 49th chapter of Vamana Purana mentiones Vijayasri/Vijayavalli as Jayasri and her birth:-

> And they glorified her through hymns in the sacrifices together with Brahman The Kşatrıyas spoke of the red coloured one as **Jayasri** who, O chief of demons, earned glory in company with Indra and Manu The Vaisyas always glorify the yellow robed one of golden body So also the Prajapatıs praised her by the name of Lakşmı The Südras extolled the blue bodied one devotedly by the name of Sridevi along with the demons, and Raksasas Thus the women were divided separately by the disous bearing lord.

So, Lord Vishnu is revatively her father and there was a point, as follows,

"Sri" means Lakshmi. So, Vijayasri/Vijayavalli/Jayasri is Vijayalakshmi, the one of Astha Lakshmi. You can ask, Is Sudharshana Chakra an avatar of Vishnu. Let me explain:-

Sudharshana Chakra is incarnation of Kama, according to Garuda Purana's Moksha or Brahma Khanda. [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370752.html) from Skanda Purana mentiones Kama is the form of Pradyumna, Vishnu's Vyuha form. So, Sudharshana Chakra is indirectly an avatar of Vishnu and Vijayalakshmi is a form of Lakshmi.

**(To be updated)**