# Does Sudarshana Chakra also have an anthropomorphic form?

Tags: reference-request, sudarshana-chakra

[Who is Vijayavalli, wife of the Sudarshana Chakra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22646/who-is-vijayavalli-wife-of-the-sudarshana-chakra)

Does Sudarshana also have a human form?

Is Sudarshana Chakra equated to Brahman?

Ideally, I would like an answer from Canonical Sanskrit scriptures composed in Aryaavarta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Human form of sudarshanachakra described in [naradapurANa ch.76](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.21516/page/n172/mode/1up) :**

> *3. Listen O Narada to what I shall say for dispelling your doubts and as to how **Kartavlrya** has attained the status of one worthy of
> being served.*
>
> *4. He was the **incarnation of Sudarsana Cakra** on the earth.*

**Consort of sudarshana as per [naradapurANa ch.77](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.21516/page/n186/mode/1up) :**

> *24. May the deity accompanied by **Vijayasri** (glory of conquest) protect my upper direction. He is the lord himself holding the
> thousand-spoked (discus). He is the person striking terror into all
> wicked ones.*

**brahma related epithets of sudarshanachakra as per [naradapurANa ch.77](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.21516/page/n193/mode/1up) :**

> *102-114. ...**Brahmajneya** (one who is comprehensive only to Brahma) **Sanatana** (the eternal one)...*

**Description in [rAmAyaNa-yuddhakhanDa-ch93](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga93/yuddha_93_frame.htm) :**

> *शरीरनाभिसत्त्वार्चिः शरारं नेमिकार्मुकम् | ज्याघोषतलनिर्घोषन् तेजोबुद्धिगुणप्रभम् || ९३-६-२९ दिव्यास्त्रगुणपर्यन्तं निघ्नन्तन् युधि
> राक्षसान् | ददृशू **रामचक्रन्** तत्कालचक्रमिव प्रजाः || ९३-६-३०*
>
> *The created beings saw that **Rama in the form of a discus**, which was killing the demons on the battle-field, like the "Wheel of Time",
> for its flame, the arrows for its spokes, his bow for the felly of the
> wheel, the twanging of the bow-string and the clanging of the gauntlet
> for the sound produced for its revolution, his energy and the virtues
> for its radiance and the power of his mystic missiles for its edge.*

Comment: I think Vijayasri is probably Vijayalakshmi because the word "Sri" is another name for Lakshmi.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from that which is stated in the *Nāradapurāṇa*, *Sudarśana cakra* is separately worshipped in a personified form for seeking protection from enemies. Here is His *dhyānamantra* from the *Śāradātilaka Tantra*.

> कल्पान्तार्कप्रकाशं त्रिभुवनमखिलं तेजसा पूरयन्तं ।
> रक्ताक्षं पिङ्गकेशं रिपुकुलभयदं भीमदंष्ट्राट्टहासं ।।
> चक्रं शङ्खं गदाब्जे पृथुतरमुषलं चापपाशाङ्कुशान् स्वैः ।
> बिभ्राणां दोर्भिराद्यं मनसि मुररिपुं भावयेच्चक्रसंज्ञम् ।।
>
> Translation: I mentally contemplate upon that discus who is the enemy of *Mura*, who is filling the 3 cosmic realms with splendour emanating out of his brilliance which is comparable to that of the blazing sun destined to end the world at the end of a *kalpa*, who has red eyes, tawny hair, fear-inspiring teeth & a boisterous laughter that generates fear amongst the hoard of enemies, and who wields a discus, conchshell, mace, lotus, a thick pestle, bow (loaded with arrows according to the commentator *Rāghavabhaṭṭa*), noose & goad in his hands.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the Human Form of Sudarshan Chakra.:

**Sri Shiva Purana 5.1.:**

> **Upamanyu said:—**
>
> 12. O Kṛṣṇa, great devotee of Śiva, listen to the glory of Śiva which I have witnessed myself. It is excellent story that enhances devotion to Śiva.
> 13. While performing penance, I saw Śiva, his weapons, his followers and Viṣṇu and other gods.
>
> .
>
> **28. I saw the discus Sudarśana in the shape of a human being with a thousand faces and two thousand hands. It was divine and lordly.**
>
> **29. It had two thousand eyes of fiery brilliance, and one thousand legs. It shone like a crore suns. It was capable of burning the three worlds.**

I hope this clarifies your queries.