# Mentions of bacteria, viruses, or microbes in Hindu scripture?

Tags: scripture

Are there any references to microbes, such as bacteria or viruses, in any Hindu scripture?

Comment: Atharva-Veda is probably talking about these unseen microbes in indirect way and there are some prayers to eliminate them.But we can't say surely ,often it depends on translater how he is interpreting the hidden meaning.Will try to search.

Comment: There are several references in the Upanishads to them. But they are not referred to in the same modern words. They are referred to as creatures born of moisture or as small creatures. One such instance is Chandogya U. - V.10.8 which is a reference to those of do follow the path of the gods or the fathers after death.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Microbes in Hindu scriptures.

Yes , there is mentioning of microbes in Hinduism Scripture. Take a look at below verse from Shanti-Parva of  [**Mahabharata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a015.htm)  -Section XV.

The word krimi (कृमि) is generally used in for  such  microscopic creatures like bacteria ,virus or  other tiny worms almost invisible to human eye. Here in below verse the word Sukshma Yoni(सूक्ष्म-योनि) is used to mention microscopic organisms.

Here in this chapter Arjuna is talking about the concept of "Survival of the fittest" , which modern science stated   thousands of year later on.

---

> **सूक्ष्मयॊनीनि** भूतानि तर्क गम्यानि कानि चित |
>  पक्ष्मणॊ ऽपि निपातेन येषां सयात सकन्धपर्ययः||
>
> P.26 There are many creatures that are so minute that their existence
> can only be inferred. With the failing of the eyelids alone, they are
> destroyed.

Although  there is just mentioning of  these microbes in Mahabharata and no other details are given ,but because it's not the main topic and even  not in the scope of religious Scripture. But it's sure that the verse is talking about these microscopic organisms which gets destroyed or die within time required to close-open eyelid.i.e. very short lifespan.

Comment: The word is क्रिमि not कृमि

Comment: @Sarvabhouma HAHA , I will add the other word also in next edit. Still searching , hope that we will find some other ref.also probably from vedas/Ayurveda.

Comment: Krimi means worm and not microscopic beings like viruses.

Comment: @Rickross yes that’s what even I thought when I first read the answer...

Comment: @HayagreevRam Yes Krimi means worm. See [here](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=krimi&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3). So, this is not the correct answer.

Comment: @HayagreevRam - The general word krumi is not used for microscopic beings. But in scriptures the word krumi is used not only for worms but also for such tiny microscopic beings. So i am here talking about scripture.

Comment: @Rickross Krimi also means microbes. Proof? When the germ theory was developed, the European scientists were calling the microbes "insects", "worms", etc. It was only later that they came to called "microbes" because they were microscopic and because insects are not microscopic. Moreover, before germ theory was developed, Sri Vaishnava tradition has recorded a Chola king whom they named "krimi-kantha-chola", because he had a throat infection. This shows that Ayurveda has the concept of germs/"worms" causing infections, and the name "worm" for microbe is not unfounded.

Comment: @Ikshvaku are you asking me for proof or are you giving me some proofs?

Comment: @Rickross Giving, sorry wasn't clear.

Comment: What do kitAnu, jivAnu mean? @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Rickross I looked those up in the dictionary: Virus and bacteria. But are these words ancient or modern words after India adopted germ theory? Like are they mentioned in Ayurvedic texts?

Comment: I don't know @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Ikshvaku what does it mean by failing of the eyes, if the second part of the verse is looked into more carefully it could be talking about microbes. Someone, please elaborate on it.

Answer (score 3):

The exact word Krimi occurs in Padma Puran, that describes [8.4 million species](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/what-are-the-8-4-million-species):

> jalaja nava-laksani sthavara laksa-vimsati **krmayo** rudra-sankhyakah
> paksinam dasa-laksanam trimsal-laksani pasavah catur-laksani manusah

```
  9,00,000 species of aquatics
20,00,000 species of plants
11,00,000 species of insects/worms (Krimi)
10,00,000 species of birds
30,00,000 species of animals
  4,00,000 species of humans
```

Answer (score 2):

Sri Vaishnava tradition has recorded a Chola king whom they named ["krimi-kantha-chola"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulothunga_Chola_II), or "Chola with the infected throat". This is because he had a throat disease. This is mentioned in the 17th century Sri Vaishnava work *Prapannamrtam*, the Sri Rangam temple *Koil Olugu* (temple history), and the Sri Vaishnava guru parampara (lineage of acharyas). This is strong evidence that Ayurveda has the concept of [Germ Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_theory_of_disease) long before Europeans discovered it.

In fact, when the Europeans first discovered Germ Theory, they called the microbes "worms", "insects", etc. It was only later on that they came to be called "microbes" because they are microscopic and require a microscope to see:

> The word "bacteria" didn't exist yet, so he called these microscopic living organisms "animalcules", meaning "little animals".

> Kircher defined the invisible organisms found in decaying bodies, meat, milk, and secretions as "worms".

> In 1700, physician Nicolas Andry argued that microorganisms he called "worms" were responsible for smallpox and other diseases.[25]

> In 1720, Richard Bradley theorised that the plague and 'all pestilential distempers' were caused by 'poisonous insects', living creatures viewable only with the help of microscopes.[26]

> Source: [Germ Theory of Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_theory_of_disease#19th_and_20th_centuries)

Answer (score 2):

According to Vishnu Purana 3:7:3 life is present among very small creatures.

> This universe, composed of seven zones, with its seven subterrestrial regions, and seven spheres--this whole egg of Brahmá.--is every where swarming with living creatures, large or **small, with smaller and smallest,** and larger and largest

Answer (score 2):

Another possible reference to "microbes" (referred by "*sūkṣma-jantu*") maybe found in the Liṅga Purāṇa

> [Chapter 78](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/page/n391/mode/2up) - Part I - Liṅga Purāṇa
>
> **जंतुभिर्मिश्रिता ह्यापः सूक्ष्माभिस्तान्निहत्य तु** ।
>  यत्पापं सकलं चाद्भिरपूताभिश्चिरं लभेत् ॥ [७८.४](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%99%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D_-_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AD%E0%A5%AE) ॥
>
> > 4. **Waters are mixed with minute (*sūkṣmā*) germs. By using unfiltered water one attains the same sin as by killing them.**
>
> English Translation by Prof. J.L. Shastri