# Does karma kshyam (nullification of karma) happen for pisachas?

Tags: scripture, karma

It is well known that karma kshayam happens for humans and [other species](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/what-are-the-84-lakh-8-4-million-species).

There are some states to be experienced by sinners other than the living species listed above. It includes pisacha state.

I heard that it is not possible to nullify karma while experiencing pisacha state. And the state of karma is immutable as in sushupti.

Is it true? Which scripture says about immutability of karma for pisachas?