# Since the existence of many universes is said to be valid and true, are there different trimurtis for each universe

Tags: shiva, vishnu, gods, manuscripts, paramatma

I have read that there are multiple brahmas; One each for a universe. Also heard that there are multiple vishnus too. So does that mean there are multiple shivas as well?

P.s :I know that the concept of parabrahm is that anything & everything is parabrahm itself

Comment: From where did you hear this? Please provide references. As far as I have read, there is only ONE brahman. Manvantars, Kalpas and Universes are created and destroyed in sequences, not running in parallel. It is a forever on going process.

Comment: From the Western cosmological standpoint (to which I think you are referring in your question?), the concept of the multiverse is a theory. There is zero direct evidence. Just a speculation.

Comment: What I mean by multiverse is the existence of parallel universes. Every universe doesn't have the same people or characters

Comment: yes there are many brahmandas, each with its own brahma,shiva,indra etc. no there are no 'parallel' universes where you yourself have a different life. the concept of multi-verse/parallel is western fiction.  @sbharti

Comment: @mar sir I have 2 doubts. Is it possible that someone dies and takes birth in a different brahmanda in the next birth? And the second doubt is do the same species exist in each brahmanda or we can see some different species alien to us and not mentioned in our scriptures?

Comment: @LSSJBroly - i guess it's possible ? but because we all accumulate karma with respect to other jivas on the same planet, so in order to exhaust it, it is likely we take birth in same anda/planet so we can repay (or receive) debts incurred to other jivas.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and..what about the 2nd doubt. Could you throw some light ?? @mar

Comment: @LSSJBroly - padma puranas mention [84 lakh](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/what-are-the-84-lakh-8-4-million-species) species. i doesn't mention if different brahmandas have different species. unlikely, because creation is very precise - 'yatha purvam akalpayat' - 'as it was in previous kalpa' - is the saying how brahma creates universe.. sun/moon/planets etc. exactly as they were before.

Comment: @mar sir thanks a lot for clearing the doubt!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept of multiple universes is present in [yoga vasistha](https://www.amazon.in/Vasisthas-Yoga-Special-Paper-27/dp/0791413640/ref=mp_s_a_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=vasistha%27s+yoga&qid=1627891452&sr=8-5). From the yoga vasistha, that is translated by Swami Venkatesananda -

> O Rama, countless have been the universes that have come into being and that have been dissolved. In fact, even the countless universes that exist at this moment are impossible to conceive of. All this can immediately be realised in one’s own heart, for these universes are the creation of the desires that arise in the heart, like castles built in the air. (The story of Suka)

> In the infinite consciousness, in every atom of it, universes come and go like particles of dust in a beam of sunlight that shines through a hole in the roof. These come and go like ripples on the ocean. (The story of Lila)

> Millions of universes appear in the infinite consciousness like specks of dust in a beam of light streaming into a room through a hole in the roof. But, even as such specks of dust are not to be seen in the outside sunlight itself, the world is not seen in the supreme non-dual consciousness.

Now to answer the main question -

> **Of those countless universes**, O Rama , in some there are only plants; **some have Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra and others as the presiding deities, and some have none at all;** in some there are only animals and birds; in some there is only an ocean; some are solid rocks; some are inhabited only by worms; some are pervaded by dense darkness; in some gods dwell; some are forever illumined. Some seem to be heading towards dissolution; some seem to be falling in space towards destruction. Since consciousness exists everywhere for ever, creation of these universes and their dissolution also goes on everywhere for ever. All these are held together by a mysterious omnipresent power. , everything exists in the one infinite consciousness; everything arises from it; it alone is everything. (The story of Lila).

Thus, trimurtis are not present in every universe.

Comment: Since Yoga Vasistha is authoritative text philosophical discourse, this should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Trimurtis are present in every Brahmanda.

> This Lord, or Isvara, has three aspects: as Brahma He creates, as
> Vishnu He preserves, and as Siva He destroys. These three form as one
> Lord, or God, who is known by three different names according to His
> three functions. **Since the Brahmandas are without number, so too are
> Brahmas, Vishnus, and Sivas without number.** The Purana says: 'One
> maybe able to count the number of sands on the seashore, but one
> cannot count the number of the Brahmandas or the deities controlling
> them.

**The Upanishads, Discussion of Brahman in the Upanishads, The Great Lord (Mahesvara), by Swami Nikhilananda**

> The constituents of creation beginning with mahat (intellect) and
> ending with Visesa [1] (earth) generate the cosmic egg, whence Brahma
> arose like a water-bubble.

**Linga Purana I.3.28**

[1] The group of seven beginning with mahat (intellect) and ending with visesa (bhutas) constitutes the Cosmic Egg which is material, though it derives its potency of consciousness (cetanata) from Purusa.

> He alone is Rudra and Vishnu pervading the universe. These worlds are
> within that cosmic egg and this universe is within it.

**Linga Purana I.3.29**

> The cosmic egg is externally enveloped by water ten times its
> magnitude. The water is externally enveloped by fire ten times its
> mass. The air is externally enveloped by the ether ten times its
> magnitude. The ether is enveloped by ego the cause of sound. The ego
> is enveloped by intellect and intellect is enveloped by Pradhana. They
> say that the coverings of the cosmic egg are seven [2]. There within
> is Brahma seated on the lotus. There are crores and crores of such
> eggs in existence.

**Linga I.3.30-33**

[2] The seven sheaths of the Cosmic Egg consist of intellect (mahat), ego (ahankara), and five subtle elements (tanmatras). (Vayu Purana 4.87, Kurma Purana I.4.46)

> **In all these cosmic eggs there are four-faced Brahmas, Vishnus and
> Rudras.** They are all created by Pradhana after coming into contact
> with Siva.

**Linga Purana I.3.34**